# Linear map having finite norm in image

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

So, I have $f:K^d \to X$, where K is a field, and X is given normed space, where $f$ is supposed to be linear. Now, book states that if $e_k$ is a member of a standard basis for $K^d$ then $||f(e_k)||$ is finite. Now, the greatest perfectionist that I know wrote the book, so this must be true, but I am either tired or stupid and I do not see why. I just think that this has to be related to the fact from linear algebra that linear map maps basis to basis, unformally speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the book is using a very unconventional notion of norm, it is because norms are always finite. For *any* vector $v \in K^d$ one should have that $\|f(v)\|$ is finite, simply because $f(v) \in X$. ([By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition), a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ maps elements of $X$ into $[0,\infty)$.)

Comment: Thanks, Dan! That is what I did not see.